# Can't run command using OpenSSH on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, windows-server-2008, openssh

I've just installed Win32-OpenSSH (from github) on Windows Server 2008 R2. It's up and running.

Now I'm trying to connect from another host. The connection is established but I can't send commands.

When trying with ssh.exe, I get this:

```
ssh administrator@MYHOST dir
administrator@MYHOST's password:
Connection reset by MYHOST
```

(password is correct)

When trying with Putty, I can login but the console is stuck after I enter a command ("dir") and pressing on ENTER. See:

```
login as: administrator
administrator@MYHOST's password:
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

administrator@MYHOST C:\Users\Administrator>dir
```

Do you know this problem?
I did not change any parameter on configuration file.

Thank you

Note:

- I get the same problem when connecting from Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7
- I get the same behaviour when trying to connect to another account
  Thank you

Comment: 1. Try to run `ssh` in debug mode (`-vvv` switches) and see at what point does it fail. 2. Have a look into the log why does the server fail. I believe windows has something like this. If not, run the server in debug mode (`-Dddd` switches to `sshd`), try to connect and see when does it fail.

Comment: I now see that if I install same package on Windows 7 it works with no problem. No firewall is running on both hosts. 

I'm now trying what you said. Thanks